# R - Connecting to file without loading

Tags: r, dbf

Is there a way to connect to a DBF and work on it without loading the file completely into memory?

I understand that the `foreign` package can be used to read DBFs, but this method loads the file into memory. This is problematic if the DBF in question is heavy in terms of file size. I'm aware of solutions that enable loading of heavy files into memory, but any solution that connects to the file and makes changes to it without loading it into memory is welcome.

Comment: Did you try the package `RODBC`

Comment: @MichaelVine Doesn't `RODBC` connect to a server? (Do tell if otherwise). I'm looking for solutions that will connect to a file on a local folder.

Comment: This was the package an instructor had us use to connect to access databases for and assignment. At [Rpubs](https://rpubs.com/ibzom/379656) i show the process. It connects without loading the whole database.